# Qual constante declarar em PDO::PARAM_ para inserir data (yyyy-mm-dd h::m:s) no mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Preciso passar uma data para o banco de dados. Utilizarei a class PDO, mas tenho a seguinte duvida. Na hora de criar o "bindValue()" que tipo de constante devo declarar em PDO::PARAM_ ?

Comment: `PDO::PARAM_STR` essa

Comment: Constante string ?

Comment: é sim para gravar datas no formato `yyyy-mm-dd h:m:s` ou `yyyy-mm-dd`  no PDO é `PDO::PARAM_STR` só lembrando que a data tem que esta no formato que o banco aceita ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para datas, sempre o padrão, que é `PDO::PARAM_STR`. De qualquer modo, quando se escreve uma query normal, a data é enviada como `string`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374631/pdoparam-for-dates